# DB Error=ORA-01407: cannot update ("XXX"."XXX"."VALUE") to NULL.

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I have (simplified for this question) a table 'TAB' with two columns 'id' (integer and not null in db) and 'value' (varchar and not null in db). I am using a java application to update 'value' column for multiple rows in one go (which is my requirement). I have used update statement with case and when keyword. The query is being generated at runtime depending on number of rows modified.

The query works fine if data is updated for all rows together, but it gives me error when updated for less rows. Say we have three rows with id = 1, 2 and 3 with values A ,B and C resp.
When the query is fired for all three rows together then it works fine

```
UPDATE 
     TAB set value = CASE 
       WHEN id = 1 THEN 'X' WHEN id = 2 THEN 'Y' WHEN id = 3 THEN 'Z' 
END
```

But when the query is fired for less than three rows then I am encountering with a DB error.

```
UPDATE TAB set value = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'X' END
```

Results in following error:

> DB Error=ORA-01407: cannot update ("XXX"."XXX"."VALUE") to NULL.

I know this is happening because the 'value' column is not null in DB. I want to know whether the above query is trying to update all the remaining values with NULL?

The query works fine if I add ELSE part as written below.

```
UPDATE TAB set value = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'X' ELSE TAB.value END
```

Will the above query impact any performance issue, if there are multiple rows in DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing this is perfectly fine.

```
UPDATE TAB set value = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'X' ELSE TAB.value END
```

other solution could be using `where` clause

```
UPDATE TAB set value = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'X' when ID = 2 then 'Y' END where id in ( 1, 2 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to know which one is better. Please share if you have any idea.

Comment: The first version is ***not*** perfectly fine. It processes all records, yet the `CASE` statement returns `NULL` for every `id` other than `1`. This means that the `NOT NULL` constraint will cause an error if there are *any* records where `id <> 1` *(as experienced by the OP - imperical evidence that it just is NOT okay...)*

Comment: @vishalKumar I would say use `where` clause to filter out the potential rows which are going to be affected.

Comment: @Dems first sql statement will not throw any exception ( check `ELSE` clause ). But even then it is not advisable as it is going to parse whole table.

Comment: Ahhh, my bad, I assumed it was the same as the OP's example when you wrote; `The way you are doing this is perfectly fine.` I'd have expected you to mention that you added the `ELSE` *(and why)* just incase the reader is a moron *(like me!)* ;)

Comment: @Dems :) That SQL is copied from the question itself :) . Check last SQL in question. I didn't add even a single char :P

Comment: @vishalKumar - I agree with RakeshJuyal - If you only want to process specific rows, use the `WHERE` clause to constrain the query.  The alternative involves changing every record every time.  Even if you set the value to the same value as it is already, it will still;  force the row to be read into memory from the disk, cause a pointless write to the table (setting the value to what it is already), fire triggers, check constraints, etc, etc.

Comment: @rakeshJuyal - Argh!!!  I'm going home.  To search for my last remaining brain cell.  And my glasses.

Answer (score 4):

You are updating all the rows in the table. This is because you don't have a **where** clause.

To update one row add a where clause.

```
UPDATE TAB set value = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'X' END where id = 1;
```

Or in your 3-row case,

```
UPDATE TAB set value = CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'X' WHEN id = 2 THEN 'Y'
WHEN id = 3 THEN 'Z' END where id in ( 1,2,3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know for one row I can use where clause, but there could be any number of rows either 1 or 2 or 3. It depends on GUI user operation. Sorry, it was not mentioned previously.

Comment: @vishalKumar if you are dynamically generating the CASE statement, why not dynamically generate the where clause as well? Be careful of `SQL Injection` attacks - always treat the user input.

Comment: @vishalKumar I suppose you are creating `case when ` dynamically based on user selection in GUI. Similarly you can create `where` clause too. Should not be a big deal.

Comment: Yes, I can add where clause dynamically and that not requires much effort. Thank you guys for giving your valuable time and answers.